# Ошибка: "Declaration expected but identifier 'RegisterClass' found"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, синтаксис, сериализация

Не работает

```
RegisterClass(Tfolder); //(для последующей сериализации)
```

Выдает ошибку

> `[Error] Unit1.pas(327): Declaration expected but identifier 'RegisterClass' found`

хотя модуль Classes подключен.

Comment: Где-то `begin..end` не закрыт, скорее всего, или, наоборот, лишний `end`.

Answer (score 1):

В `uses Windows` подключен или `SysUtils`, точно не знаю, в каком из них этот метод. Так что проверь оба.